# Spark: Logistic regression

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

This code works great!

```
val model = new LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS().setNumClasses(2).run(training)
```

I am able to call model.predict(...)

However, when I try to setup the model parameters, I can't call model.predict
For example, with the following code, I can't call predict on model variable.

```
val model = new LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS().setNumClasses(2)

model.optimizer.setUpdater(new L1Updater).setRegParam(0.0000001).setNumIterations(numIterations)
 model.run(training)
```

Any help with this will be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because `model` in the second case is `LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS` not `LogisticRegressionModel`. What you need is something like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.{
  LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS, LogisticRegressionModel}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.optimization.L1Updater

// Create algorithm instance
val lr: LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS = new LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS()
  .setNumClasses(2)

// Set optimizer params (it modifies lr object)
lr.optimizer
  .setUpdater(new L1Updater)
  .setRegParam(0.0000001)
  .setNumIterations(numIterations)

// Train model
val model: LogisticRegressionModel = lr.run(training)
```

Now model is `LogisticRegressionModel` and can be used for predictions.